# Can I reverse the order of a multicast delegate event?

Tags: c#, events

When you subscribe to an event in .NET, the subscription is added to a multicast delegate.  When the event is fired, the delegates are called in the order they were subscribed.

I'd like to override the subscription somehow, so that the subscriptions are actually fired in the **reverse** order.  Can this be done, and how?

I think something like this might be what I need?:

```
public event MyReversedEvent
{
    add { /* magic! */ }
    remove { /* magic! */ }
}
```

Comment: I thought the order the subscriptions were fired was indeterminate.

Comment: @ChrisF: From MSDN..."A MulticastDelegate has a linked list of delegates, called an invocation list, consisting of one or more elements. When a multicast delegate is invoked, the delegates in the invocation list are called synchronously in the order in which they appear."

Comment: @Robert - Ah, I clearly glossed over the **multicast** bit - time to stop looking for questions to answer & go to bed.

Comment: Can I ask why?  This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Doesn't this create tight logic between the publisher and the subscribers, which is the exact thing this pattern is meant to avoid?

Comment: Though you may find ways to do it. I would still like to know the reason for which you need to do this !!!
In my understanding, the order in which events are handled by various objects should not be based on any order and neither should be based on any logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Controlling When and If a Delegate Fires Within a Multicast Delegate](http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharpckbk2/Delegates,-Events,-and-Anonymous-Methods/Controlling-When-and-If-a-Delegate-Fires-Within-a-Multicast-Delegate/)**

The following method creates a multicast delegate called allInstances and then uses GetInvocationList to allow each delegate to be fired individually, in reverse order:

```
public static void InvokeInReverse()
{
    MyDelegate myDelegateInstance1 = new MyDelegate(TestInvoke.Method1);
    MyDelegate myDelegateInstance2 = new MyDelegate(TestInvoke.Method2);
    MyDelegate myDelegateInstance3 = new MyDelegate(TestInvoke.Method3);

    MyDelegate allInstances =
            myDelegateInstance1 +
            myDelegateInstance2 +
            myDelegateInstance3;

    Console.WriteLine("Fire delegates in reverse");
    Delegate[] delegateList = allInstances.GetInvocationList();
    for (int counter = delegateList.Length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
    {
        ((MyDelegate)delegateList[counter])();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried this myself just before you posted your answer and got it working - good to see confirmation that I've done the right thing. :)

Answer (score 22):

You don't need any magic; you just need to reverse the addition.
Writing `delegate1 + delegate2` returns a new delegate containing the method(s) in `delegate1` followed by the methods in `delegate2`.

For example:

```
private EventHandler myReversedEventField;
public event EventHandler MyReversedEvent
{
    add { myReversedEventField = value + myReversedEventField; }
    remove { myReversedEventField -= value; }
}
```

You don't need any magic in the `remove` handler, unless you want to remove the last occurrence of that handler instead of the first.  (In case the same handler was added twice)

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a little, please?  It would be good to see the context around the code you posted, so I can see where I should put it.

Comment: @Neil, Some background information here: http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/2007/07/25/intercepting-add-and-remove-of-c-event-delegates/

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to handle this when you raise the event.  You can get the event subscribers via [Delegate.GetInvocationList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx), and just call each delegate in reverse order yourself.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this myself just before you posted your answer and got it working - good to see confirmation that I've done the right thing. :)

Comment: @SLaks: Interesting.  Thanks - hadn't used the delegate operators in that way before...